# ScrollBar Disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollbar

I was trying to implement a ScrollViewer like so;

```
<Height="auto" Width="auto"
            MaxHeight="500" MaxWidth="400"
            ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer Name="scrlBr">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Name ="txtBlock" Margin="10" Height="auto" 
Width="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                        <Button Name="btnOk" Click="btnOk_Click" Width="80"
HorizontalAlignment="Center">Close!</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="3" 
Name="lblScrollDown">\/</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

The problem I'm having is that the scroll bar appears disabled, while the text obviously goes down off the window and I can't see the `btnOk`. Surely if the window has a fixed height and the `TextBlock` and `Button`, which are contained in the `Scrollviewer`, are bigger than the window then the ScrollBar should be enabled, no?

**UPDATE**

I worked out that the problem lies in having the `ScrollViewer` within a `StackPanel`. Might try it with a `Grid` instead... Update to come.

**SOLUTION**

I was right about the `Stackpanel` being the problem and went with Heinzi's suggestion of using the `DockPanel` and all's workin' fine. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `StackPanel`. It always takes all the vertical space it needs, so the *container* of the ScrollPanel is much larger than the window itself, and the ScrollViewer sees no need to scroll.

Solution: Replace the `StackPanel` with a `DockPanel`. Move the `<Label>` declaration to the top and dock it to the bottom of the DockPanel. The last child in a DockPanel (which is the `ScrollViewer` in this case) always fills the remaining space:

```
<Grid> 
    <DockPanel> 
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ... Name="lblScrollDown">\/</Label> 
        <ScrollViewer Name="scrlBr"> 
             ...
        </ScrollViewer> 
    </DockPanel> 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `CanContentScroll` property on `True` from the ScrollViewer and set a fixed height of the StackPanel, as a StackPanel is designed to grow indefinitely in one direction. Or better, use a different panel to stack your items in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need write something like this

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrlBr" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto">
...
</ScrollViewer>
```